# JS file is not loading on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone

I have a problem that external scripts are not loaded on iphone, on ather devices it works good, on windows and android.

This is how I'm including the script

`<script src="/js/wt.js"></script>`

In dev tools it shows me that script was deleted.

Can someone help me?

I tried to add domain befor script url, to connect script at the bottom of html and at the top and it doesn't work.

Comment: 'In dev tools it shows me that script was deleted' . Do you mean that scirpt is missing . If so what is error shown

Comment: I'm facing similar issue - js file won't be loaded for iPhone but for iPad and android and web it loads .It happened all of a sudden , everything worked fine before. Can you provide more details - like phone model ,iOS version